# How can I change the font color of entire subsection?

Tags: sectioning, color

Just as the title says, I want to change the text color for the entire subsection. The subsection includes paragraphs, math mode, regular text bla bla.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `\color{red}` at the start of the section and `\color{black}` at the end.

In the standard classes at least, section headings pick up the current colour.

This of course requires the `color` or `xcolor` packages to be loaded.

Comment: May be you have to add `\everymath{\color{his_color}}`
and `\everydisplay{\color{his_color}}` to your answer... But not sure if needed and not sure if can be inside the document environment

Comment: @koleygr the OP provided no test file so hard to guess, but by default math does not normalize the colour so if the section is red the math will be as well.

Comment: thanks David... I thought that math doesn't really follow the text color... But may be I remember wrong and they just don't follow the `\bfseries`... And this is why I thought so... (Because I had to put a `\bm` there... but this is another subject )